# How to use ctypes.util.find_library to import .so libraries in AWS lambda (python)?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ocr, ctypes

## What I'm trying

A python package I'm using (OCRMYPDF) on Lambda needs the leptonica library **liblept.so.5**. On isolating the import code I found the issue is with **find_library('lept')**. Printing the result returns None.

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    liblept=find_library('lept')
    print("liblept:%s"%liblept)
```

The python package I'm using needs many native compiled dependencies. I'm trying to import these using lambda layers.

## layer structure

```
/opt/
  /opt/bin/
  /opt/lib/
    /opt/lib/liblept.so.5
  /opt/tesseract
```

I'm able to access the file using CDLL (code below). But I don't want to rewrite the package and replace every find_library() with CDLL. Is it possible to set the import directory for find_library?

```py
liblept=CDLL("/opt/lib/liblept.so.5") # found
print("liblept:%s"%liblept)
```

## My layer code works

I used a docker image to build layer. The files in /opt/bin that depend on leptonica are working (tesseract runs properly, tested OCR as well).

```py
logging.info(os.system("tesseract --version"))
```

**output**

```
START RequestId: d826d36c-4ce9-4b67-b501-8c9042edcf80 Version: $LATEST
tesseract 4.1.0
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.2.90) : libpng 1.2.49 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.3.0
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
END RequestId: d826d36c-4ce9-4b67-b501-8c9042edcf80
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested on Python:3.7 AWS lambda environment:

You need to add `liblept.so` (just rename `liblept.so.5`) to the `/lib` folder of your lambda package or in `/opt/lib` of your layer. The file must be called `liblept.so` because `find_library` only looks for `".so"` files, not `".so.5"` files:

From the python doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

```
ctypes.util.find_library(name)
Try to find a library and return a pathname. name is the library name without any prefix like lib, suffix like .so, .dylib or version number (this is the form used for the posix linker option -l). If no library can be found, returns None.
```

When only adding `"liblept.so"`, the linker complains that it cannot find `"liblept.so.5"`, so I also added `"liblept.so.5"` to the `lib` folder.

Maybe someone else can pitch in and find a solution that does not use a duplicate file.

AWS lambda will automatically make any file in `/opt/lib` or `/lib` available via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

On Python 3.8 you may also need to include `ld` and `objdump`, as per this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=313506, altough I have not tested that.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue and tried to create symlink instead of copying the actual file but that did not work with find_library either.

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon Linux 2 based runtimes (Python 3.8+), the utilities required to perform `ctypes.util.find_library` such as [ldconfig, ld, and gcc](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Lib/ctypes/util.py#L309-L312) have all been removed.

To correct this, I made a [Lambda Container Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html#build-container-image) to take the base AWS runtime image and add gcc which will locate the desired .so file.

Dockerfile example

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9-arm64

RUN yum install -y \
    gcc \
    && yum clean all

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY *.py ./
```