# How to import .so files (shared libraries) in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ctypes, amazon-ami

I'm trying to deploy .so files on Lambda using layers. The files are compiled using Amazon Linux docker image. I uploaded the layer as a zip with required files in /lib/. However my code is not able to read the files.

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    liblept=find_library('lept') # present in /opt/lib
    libpng=find_library('png') # present in Lambda's default library
    print(liblept) # gives None
    print(libpng) # gives libpng.so.4
```

I tried to add /opt/lib to **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable but it doesn't work. Turns out that LD_LIBRARY_PATH has /opt/lib by default-

```py
print(os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))
```

**output**

```
/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib
```

Comment: How is this different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083051/how-to-use-ctypes-util-find-library-to-import-so-libraries-in-aws-lambda-pytho?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? @real_shardul  @Andrew?

Comment: @ambigus9 I didn't

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083051/how-to-use-ctypes-util-find-library-to-import-so-libraries-in-aws-lambda-pytho), your problem is related to that one.