# Using .so file libraries in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, linux, aws-lambda

I have a lambda project and I need to use the bonsai library. It turns out that this library does not work in a Linux environment via pip installation. Needs to be installed manually.

With that, I installed it in Docker container following the creator's instructions and built it. After that, I saved all the content in my project as follows:
[image: Lambda Project]

When executing the lambda, the bonsai library is recognized, but within it there is the use of classes from the .so file, and at that moment the error occurs:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'init': No module named 'bonsai._bonsai'
```

Searching here on similar topics, I tried to upload the project with the .so file inside a /lib folder, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63232632/2695038

I also tried to create a layer by manually importing the so file and linking the layer to the lambda, but without success. The error persists.